# Объединить метки [криптопро] и [cryptopro]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [криптопро](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be) и [cryptopro](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cryptopro). В качестве основной предлагаю русскоязычную.

Comment: Объединить - ок, а вот на счёт русскоязычной метки как основной я не уверен.

Comment: @Suvitruf криптопро это ведь наш продукт и у него русское название) И судя по всему, вопросы как раз все по нему https://www.cryptopro.ru/

Comment: Я в курсе, просто выглядит как-то странно о_О

Comment: @Suvitruf normal'no viglyadit!

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю создать метку [крипто-про](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be) и обе вышеуказанные присоединить к ней. Ну или русскоязычную переименовать в мой вариант, если так можно, не столь важно.

Имхо, читается и воспринимается легче.